# XML parsing : Encoding is wrong

Tags: python, encoding, elementtree

I want to parse a XML file that start in the following way:

```
<BAHFeed xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" GeneratedAt="2015-11-10T12:01:10.1776621+01:00" Type="Sport" BettingOfferId="1" Lang="en">
```

When trying to parse this xml:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
...
tree = ET.fromstring(xml)
```

I get the following error message:

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: encoding specified in XML declaration is incorrect: line 1, column 30
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Are You sure that in xml You have string with that xml or maybe it's something else ? I checked and that code works https://gist.github.com/nuncjo/0612bcd972ad7e761753 .

Comment: I just discovered that the xml data is actually encoded as UTF-16. So a `xml.encode("utf-16")` did solve the problem. Thanks for reading anyway.